# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException occurs upon retrieving external storage path android

Tags: android, android-studio, file-permissions, android-permissions

I have implemented an android application which uses device camera to take images. I want to save the images to the external storage directory of device. I have been following the instructions given [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) in android documentation to achieve this.

Here is my code:

I have added the provider in manifest file.

```
<provider
        android:authorities="com.efftronics.android.eEmployee.provider"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

In `xml` folder, I created `paths.xml` file and defined the path elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
        <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
    </paths>
```

Here is the Java code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                //mContext.checkImageDirectories();
                String fileName = EmpConstants.startImgName +
                        new SimpleDateFormat(EmpConstants.PhotoFileFormat, Locale.US).format(new Date());
                File outFile = new File(
                        mContext.getEmpImageDirPath() + fileName + ".jpg");
               // File newfile = new File(outFile,"default_image.jpg");
               /* mCurrentPhotoPath = outFile.getPath();
                cameraOpeningIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outFile));*/
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",outFile));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                /*cameraOpeningIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);*/

                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }


        public String getEmpImageDirPath() {
          try {
            return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString()
                    + EmpConstants.appDir;
              } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.d("eEmp/ImgDir", e.toString());
              return "";
        }
}
```

Now when I open the camera, the following exception is thrown:

> Error raised due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/eEmployee/IMG_20180103_150825.jpg

I am unable to figure out the reason for this exception. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you expand and copy the full error log here?

Comment: I have expanded log error. please check the question once @anthonymonori

Comment: I mean that it would be great if you could copy more than just a single line, but rather several more that may help us get an idea what could be the root-cause. I also would suggest that you use something like pastebin.com and link us to the full output of your run!

Comment: Please post the code that produces this exception. It has nothing to do with a camera i think. And all with how you use your file provider. Post a normal stacktrace.

Comment: `<files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>`. That indeed does not suit files on `/storage/emulated/0/......`. So no wonder that getUriForFile() trows that exception long before you try to start the camera app.

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with trying to obtain a camera permission. And you will have that exception under all android versions. The subject of your post makes no sense.

Comment: I'm new to android so i don't know where to change please suggest me.It's only occuring for nougat versions @greenapps

Comment: Please start with changing the subject of your post as you now know which function throws the exception. And that it has nothing to do with a camera.

Comment: `.It's only occuring for nougat versions `. No. It happens always when you call getUriForFile(). On all versions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>` element in `<paths>` in paths.xml file. The link you are following states that:

> `<files-path name="name" path="path" />` Represents files in the `files/`         subdirectory of your app's internal storage area. This subdirectory is the same as the value returned by `Context.getFilesDir()`.

Similarly it also states that:

> `<external-path name="name" path="path" />`Represents files in the root of the external storage area. The root path of this subdirectory is the same as the value returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

From the code that you have shared above, we can see that you are using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` in your function `getEmpImageDirPath()`.

So to resolve the error, you have to replace `<files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>`by `<external-path name="my_images" path="images/" />`